# How to update existing project to entity framework 5.0

Tags: entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework project. I want to update it to EF 5. I used NuGet with this command:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
```

to install EF 5.0. It added lines to my config file:

```
<section name="entityFramework"
         type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
         requirePermission="false" />
```

Is this enough upgrade my project to EF 5.0? Is this the right way to do the update?

Comment: It should be enough.. are you having problems with it?

Comment: no but i saw same system.data.entity it is version 4.0. i wonder maybe it isnt enough. i dont know how is upgrade.

Comment: you need change the project to use .Net 45

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need change your project to use .Net 4.5 to take advantage of a lot of EF5 improvements. Here is a blog from team. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/08/15/ef5-released.aspx

Compatibility

This version of the NuGet package is fully compatible with Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 and can be used for applications targeting .NET 4.0 and 4.5.

**Some features are only available when writing an application that targets .NET 4.5. This includes enum support, spatial data types, table-valued functions and the performance improvements.**